# TypeError: Batching of padded sparse tensors is not currently supported on padding a TF dataset object

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to train a model for detecting an object from a drawing. I am using tensorflow. I have made a function using the input_fn provided by Google for the QuickDraw dataset. But I am getting the mentioned error on running the function. The code for the function is:

```
def input_func():
        """ 
        The input function for estimator

        Returns:
            Dictionary of features
            Target labels
        """
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(tfrecord_path)
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            dataset  = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = 10)
        dataset = dataset.repeat()
        dataset = dataset.interleave(
            tf.data.TFRecordDataset,
            cycle_length=10,
            block_length=1
        )
        dataset = dataset.map(
            functools.partial(parse_tfexample,mode = mode),
            num_parallel_calls=10
        )
        dataset =  dataset.prefetch(1000000)
        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
            dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000000)
        dataset = dataset.padded_batch(
            batch_size, padded_shapes = dataset.output_shapes
        )
        features, labels = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

        return features, labels
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\Train_Model.py", line 298, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\Train_Model.py", line 209, in main
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 471, in train_and_evaluate
    return executor.run()
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 610, in run
    return self.run_local()
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\training.py", line 711, in run_local
    saving_listeners=saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 354, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1207, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1234, in _train_model_default
    input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN))
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1075, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode))
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1162, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "A:\Code\Machine Learning\Software Engineering project\Quick Draw\Train_Model.py", line 64, in input_func
    batch_size, padded_shapes = dataset.output_shapes
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 945, in padded_batch
    drop_remainder)
  File "C:\Users\shind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 2505, in __init__
    "Batching of padded sparse tensors is not currently supported")
TypeError: Batching of padded sparse tensors is not currently supported
```

What is the reason for the error and how to solve it?

Comment: Which version of TF are you using? Looks like you are trying to pad and batch sparse tensors which is not supported by this op. You can convert the tensor to dense and then apply the padded  batch like it's shown [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13766#issuecomment-404422719).

Comment: @kvish I am using the latest tf. Is the support been removed recently? because the code of the Google's repository has the same code as I have.

Comment: I am not sure. It could be due to variants in the versions. Is the data you are working on the same data as what is in the repo?

Comment: @kvish yes I am using the data provided by Google.

Comment: @kvish how to I convert the tensors from sparse to dense?

Comment: Can you share the link to the repo? Maybe I will be able to help you better if there are more details on how the data is!

Comment: @kvish I had the problem solved. Inside the parse_tfexample function, there was a member of parsed_features dictionary called drawing which was sparsetensor. S I just put the statement `parsed_features["drawing"] = tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed_features["drawing"])`

Comment: @kvish the link is : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/quickdraw/train_model.py

Comment: that's great! Glad it worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the parse_tfexample function. In it, there is a dictionary with an element keyed "drawing" which is a sparse tensor. So I just converted it to dense using `tf.sparse.to_dense()`. Here is the code of the parse_tfexample:

```
def parse_tfexample(example,mode):
        """Parse a single tf example"""
        features = {
            "drawing" : tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
            "shape": tf.FixedLenFeature([2],dtype=tf.int64)
        }
        if mode != tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            features["class_index"] = tf.FixedLenFeature([1],dtype=tf.int64)
        parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example,features)
        parsed_features["drawing"] = tf.sparse.to_dense(parsed_features["drawing"])
        print(parsed_features)
        labels = None
        if mode != tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
            labels = parsed_features["class_index"]

        return parsed_features, labels
```